# Как сделать полоску на элементе меню, как у гугла и icons8

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать полоску на элементе меню такую же, как на картинках?
[image]
[image]

Comment: `div - ом` или псевдо-элементом....

Comment: "Do you know de way?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с `border`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Monospace, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu {
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.list li {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.list li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border-bottom: 3px solid #1A73E8;
color: #1A73E8;
font-weight: bold;
```

Comment: Ну да еще и `border - ом` )))

Comment: или сразу нужному div или при наведении.

Comment: @Air, а что не так?

Comment: @Qwertiy,   я когда вопрос комментировал, про border забыл....  А не в том смысле что это плохо...

Answer (score 0):

```
li:hover{border-bottom:3px solid#09f;}
```

наверное как-то так